# Android data sync between multiple devices of same user

Tags: android

After doing some research I get the impression that Android does not currently support sync between devices of same user.

Lets say an app is being used by a user on a mobile and tablet (or on two mobiles or tablets). I want to be able to sync data between them. It may be things like settings etc.

I have looked at the Backup API and Google cloud messaging. I dont think either supports syncing. Backup API is close but only supposed to be used for backups after a system wipe or user changing to a new device but not syncing.

I there any other way to do syncing of an app data between devices of same user without having to introduce user logins. iOS has iCloud which lets apps sync their data. Is there no equivalent/similar feature on Android.

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

could you tie it into the google Drive (free cloud storage)? This should be already setup for just about every android user (mandatory to have a google account), and would provide a common place to stash data/settings and could be pulled back down from another device logged into the same google user account (same user).

Comment: Thanks for your reply SnakeDoc. Doing that is not impossible but probably not a clean solution either. Pushing data to google drive and pulling it down would involve doing things like conflict resolution ourselves which is not ideal and I presume it would be user visible, unwanted user modifications can break things. Plus users will probably not appreciate random app data appearing in their drive.

Comment: if you notified them of the behavior and they had to "allow" it, then its probably less of a problem... and perhaps make the directory hidden or look like something that should not be touched, like ".appsettings/" or something...  the alternative solution is you/your company hosting a server that is sent all the data/settings you would like to keep presistant across devices. There are options like Amazon's ec2, M$'s Azule, ScaleEngine, and others that are cheaper. This obviously isn't "free" to you or your company, but would give complete control over how you do the syncing.

Comment: I am aware of the alternatives. Looking to verify that there is no such framework in Android like iCloud